# Struck on Grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I used fdisk to partition a drive and after reboot, I am stuck at the grub menu. I tried a few things but got stuck at need to load kernal. Any help is much appreciated.

https://postimg.cc/MnzVw7cC

https://postimg.cc/mctcZ8T5

https://postimg.cc/BjJYz1J6

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: i think re installing is your best option at this point.please add a bit more information about what ubuntu version you are using and a bit more information about your system,please edit the information into your question.

Comment: Why are you using lvm partitions instead of primary partitions, which most people use? Nothing like making life complicated for yourself.